# Getting error in converting localDate in getString

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, dao, java-time

I am trying to get selected data from db where `presentationDateStart` and `presentationDateEnd` are `localdate`

This is my DAO:

```
public List<PresentationBean> list() throws SQLException {
        List<PresentationBean> presentations = new ArrayList<PresentationBean>();

        try (
            Connection connection = currentCon.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT presentationDateStart, presentationDateEnd FROM presentation where ROWNUM=1");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        ) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                PresentationBean presentation = new PresentationBean();
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");
                LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("presentationDateStart", formatter);   
                presentation.setPresentationDateStart(resultSet.getString(startDate)); //ERROR HERE
                presentation.setPresentationDateEnd(resultSet.getString("presentationDateEnd")); //ERROR HERE

                presentations.add(presentation);
            }
        }
```

The error said :

> no suitable method found for getString(LocalDate)
>    method ResultSet.getString(int) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; LocalDate cannot be converted to int)
>    method ResultSet.getString(String) is not applicable
>     (argument mismatch; LocalDate cannot be converted to String)

I am aware `presentationDateEnd` is an error because i did not convert it yet. I tried first for `presentationDateStart` but i did not work out. I am not sure how to convert the `localDate`. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense as is it. Instead of:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("presentationDateStart", formatter);   
presentation.setPresentationDateStart(resultSet.getString(startDate));
```

You probably meant:

```
String startDateAsString = resultSet.getString("presentationDateStart");    
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(startDateAsString, formatter);   
presentation.setPresentationDateStart(startDate);
```

Comment: @user6185827 See the change - you first need to read the date from the db as a string then convert it to a LocalDate and then set the value in your object.

Comment: So i did it on the other way round -.- OMG. Thank you